# Solr to Solr via import/update and modify data

Tags: solr

Given: running Solr v.4.6 (3.5M docs) in a closed system with a fixed data source (just queries possible)

ToDo:  Solr v.7.4

Just looking for an easy way to import complete index from v.4.6 including changing of schema to copy fields and config for facetting within searchHandler and keep it up to date against last modified date of documents. (about ~1k update titles/day)

Any recommendation to do this?

really appreciate

Francois

Comment: I'm not familiar with any automated way of migrating schema changes between versions, as the field types can have been replaced by multiple field types where they have different strengths. The largest change is probably the introduction of the point types in 7. Facet configuration should be identical. There's support in the data import handler for using a SolrEntity as the source, as long as all the fields you want to retrieve are set as stored - otherwise you'll have to go to the original source and reindex from that.

Comment: OK, i figured out to import from old Solr version. Now i need a hint to do a delta import from solr to solr against last modified date or last index time.I didnt find any examples which checks last index time from source solr.

?........... > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'

Comment: The [SolrEntityProcessor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#solrentityprocessor) supports using `fq` or `q` to give it a query. Using something like `last_modified:[${dataimporter.last_index_time} TO *]` for either of those could work.